# Summing Qtys with Matching ID in multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query that returns a results table with IDs, Qtys, and Locations. An item can be in multiple locations, so there could be four rows for a single item, each row being its own location with its own qty. Example:

```
SELECT i.ITEM_NO, SUM(w.QTY_ON_HAND - w.QTY_DAMAGED) as QTY, w.LOCATION
FROM Workshop w
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_LIST i
ON i.ITEM_ID = w.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY i.ITEM_NO, w.QTY_ON_HAND, w. QTY_DAMAGED, w.LOACTION
```

Returns:

```
-----------------------------------
|  ITEM_NO  |  QTY  |  LOCATION   | 
-----------------------------------
|  SN-15    |   0   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  SN-15    |   2   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
|  TY-14    |   1   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  TY-14    |   5   |    LAX      |
-----------------------------------
|  TY-14    |   0   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
```

What I want to do, ideally in this same query, is sum each location's qty to find the total qty for each `ITEM_NO`, with a results table looking like:

```
---------------------------
|  ITEM_NO  |  TOTAL_QTY  | 
---------------------------
|  SN-15    |       2     |
---------------------------
|  TY-14    |       6     |
---------------------------
```

What would be the best way to do this, and would I be able to do it all in one query? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to sum up the quantities of different location of same item_no than location column should be avoided and a simple group by by item_no and sum(qty) will work but if you require location too than though you sum up qty of different location of same item_no you are going to have same no. of rows as in table 1 of your question. Is that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, SUM(TOTAL_QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY FROM tablename GROUP BY ITEM_NO
```

GROUP BY will separate the results per ITEM_NO... it might sound a bit confusing but does make sense.

EDIT: after extra question

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, SUM(TOTAL_QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY FROM
(
  SELECT i.ITEM_NO, SUM(w.QTY_ON_HAND - w.QTY_DAMAGED) as QTY, w.LOCATION
  FROM Workshop w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_LIST i
  ON i.ITEM_ID = w.ITEM_ID
  GROUP BY i.ITEM_NO, w.QTY_ON_HAND, w. QTY_DAMAGED, w.LOACTION
) AS query1
GROUP BY ITEM_NO
```

What you're doing here is using the results of the query you made as the table to query the sums from.
Every result of a query can be used as if it were a table in the database.

Comment: So I see how that works, but can I combine that with the original results query into a single query? I added the original query that returns the first results table to the question at the top. Is there a way to nest this solution with the original query so it can be done all at once? Or would I have to run multiple queries? Thanks!

Comment: I just edited my reply with what you'll need... let me know if you're still missing something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic aggregation query.  If you are going to use SQL effectively, you should learn the basics of the language:

```
select t.item_no, sum(t.qty) as total_qty
from table t
group by t.item_no;
```

`group by` is a fundamental part of the language.

EDIT:

Of course.  The simplest way is to use `with`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT i.ITEM_NO, SUM(w.QTY_ON_HAND - w.QTY_DAMAGED) as QTY, w.LOCATION
      FROM Workshop w LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ITEM_LIST i
           ON i.ITEM_ID = w.ITEM_ID
      GROUP BY i.ITEM_NO, w.QTY_ON_HAND, w. QTY_DAMAGED, w.LOCATION
     )
select t.item_no, sum(t.qty) as total_qty
from table t
group by t.item_no;
```

But, this query doesn't really make sense.  You don't need the two quantities in the `group by`.  So, try this:

```
with t as (
      SELECT i.ITEM_NO, SUM(w.QTY_ON_HAND - w.QTY_DAMAGED) as QTY, w.LOCATION
      FROM Workshop w LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ITEM_LIST i
           ON i.ITEM_ID = w.ITEM_ID
      GROUP BY i.ITEM_NO, w.LOCATION
     )
select t.item_no, sum(t.qty) as total_qty
from table t
group by t.item_no;
```

And a further simplification is simply:

```
      SELECT i.ITEM_NO, SUM(w.QTY_ON_HAND - w.QTY_DAMAGED) as QTY
      FROM Workshop w LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ITEM_LIST i
           ON i.ITEM_ID = w.ITEM_ID
      GROUP BY i.ITEM_NO
```

Comment: why are you adding an alias to a table if you never use it?

Comment: @Dominique . . . I almost always add aliases.

Comment: I only add them when I'm joining tables... but when I'm adding them I also use them.  Now the alias is added for no use at all... on high traffic servers every microsecond counts.

Comment: So I see how that works, but can I combine that with the original results query into a single query? I added the original query that returns the first results table to the question at the top. Is there a way to nest this solution with the original query so it can be done all at once? Or would I have to run multiple queries? Thanks!

Comment: @tsHunter . . . See the edits.  The final query is what you want.  Your query should not be aggregating by the two quantity fields.